# Excel Web Part - remove options from drop down list?

Tags: 2013, web-part, excel-web-access-webpart

I have a site that contains an Excel web part.  The web part has a drop down list for named ranges on the Excel file.  The DDL has many names/options that don't appear in my named ranges.  Is there any way to remove some of these options from the DDL in the web part?